# Given that $-1 \le a \le 1$ and -1 < b < 1 show that $- 1 - ab \le a + b \le 1+ab $.

Tags: inequality

I've managed to show that -2< a+b <2 and 0<1+ab<2 if that helps at all. I originally thought that because a+b<2 and 1+ab<2 that I could then conclude that a+b<1+ab, however I'm pretty sure that this is not the case. Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints**: Show that the following inequalities follow from the given assumptions:
$$
0\leq(1+a)(1+b),\quad 0\leq(1-a)(1-b).
$$
Then expand them.